# How do I find a solution to this pde?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

How would I find a general solution to the following pde:
$$\frac{\partial^2U(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+U(x,y)=0$$

Comment: You can solve this by direct integration.

Comment: I don't fully understand how to integrate partial derivatives

Comment: Hint: your pde is actually an ODE with the derivative being with respect to $x$, think of y as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

We see that only the partial derivative with respect to one of the variables enters the equation. In such cases we can treat the equation as an ODE in the variable in which partial derivatives enter the equation, keeping in mind that the constants of integration may depend on the other variables.

For $y$ fixed (treated as constant) $U(x,y)$ depends on $x$ and you can put  $U(x,y)=\varphi(x)$ and the equation 
$$
\frac{\partial^2U(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+U(x,y)=0
$$
becomes
$$
\varphi''(x)+\varphi(x)=0
$$
that is easy to integrate.
So we have
$$
\varphi(x)=A\cos x+B\sin x
$$
Since the constants may depend on the other variable $y$, the general solution of the PDE will be
$$
U(x,y)=A(y)\cos x+B(y)\sin x
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary functions. To check that this is indeed a solution, simply substitute the expression back into the equation.